# Scale background image in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I'm having the following problem;

I have a LinearLayout with in it a ScrollView, in the ScrollView is some custom view. Now I want to put an image in the background of the LinearLayout and keep the image in its original size. But when I set the background property of the LinearLayout it stretches to fit the full screen. How can I make it so that the image keeps its original size?

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/root"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/some_drawable">
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <some.custom.layout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seeing some people upvoting this question every now and again (thanks for that!) but would like to put a disclaimer here that this question is now 9 years old and a lot has happened in the Android world. It is very likely that there are better ways to solve this problem by now!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using FrameLayout with an ImageView and LinearLayout inside. For example, try changing the alpha of the image and move it to foreground in your FrameLayout, thus the LinearLayout stays on background. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works well, but a more elegant solution I think, can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781593/background-image-placement

Answer (score 28):

Code example for Egor's answer:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/layoutLogin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/layoutLogin"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/layoutLogin"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layoutLogin"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_photo_bg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to ColdForged's suggestion, you could move from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and use `ImageView` to show the image instead of changing background to it. The views in `RelativeLayout` can interfere unlike in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I've tried this, but how do I draw the content of the ScrollView over the image view so that the image is the background?

Comment: Maybe by setting alpha for scrollview background

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [InsetDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html). Either that or it would likely require you to subclass your layout to draw the way you wish as the background element doesn't have the ability you need.