# how can scroll background image?

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, scrollview, background-image

How can I set my background image to scroll with my ScrollView?
For example, I want to appear one image 640x480 and if you slide down it must appear the other 480 dp of my image..

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833943/scale-background-image-in-linearlayout, that should solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<ScrollView> 
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView>  with "wrap_content","wrap_content" and App background here
.
.
.
```

I have not try this but I guess it will work..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with scrollView but if you want to change your application to scroll horizontally you might consider implement a ViewPager and set a different background at each page. It will smoothly switch between pages displaying different picture on the full screen. You might want to check this tutorial: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Comment: no, I want to scroll with my listview in vertical. My image must slide in vertical. thanks for help