# Android ImageButton fit height to width during onCreateView()?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

please help me, how to align the height to width. I've tried everything, it is not working.
Edit: Added full layout.

[image]

The code to create the button looks like this

```
LinearLayout showLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.show_full_btn);
showButton = new ImageButton(activityContext);

<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/count"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/w_tv"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:typeface="normal"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/show_full_btn"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want ?equal width and height?

Comment: yes, Image Width is the width of the layout, making the height is the same as the width. That picture is not stretched.

Comment: Please post your full XML

Comment: posted full layout

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `android:scaleType` to a `LinearLayout` which is not applicable, it works with ImageButtons, so declare your view as an `ImageButton` instead and apply `scalyType` to it, or if you kinda stuck with a layout, just make [as this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837050/1638739):

> Try using FrameLayout with an ImageView and LinearLayout inside. For
>   example, try changing the alpha of the image and move it to foreground
>   in your FrameLayout, thus the LinearLayout stays on background.

Comment: I packed ImageButton into LinearLayout, but scaleType for ImageButton does not work. The result is the same.

Comment: <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/show_full_btn_layout"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/show_full_btn"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:orientation="horizontal">
</ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: just make your ImageButton `width` and `height` as `match_parent` if you want the image to fill the whole LinearLayout it wrapped into.

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding it difficult to get your results from the XML layout, then try to do it within the onCreate method of your activity. You can easily get it done.

Comment: I have created ImageButton from the code, but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about an `ImageButton` in your question, but have not used an `ImageButton` in your XML, just `LinearLayout`. Also, in your java, the `showLayout` and `showButton` are two separate variables, and not connected.