# BitmapDrawable aligned as background

Tags: android, bitmap, gravity

I'm wondering if it's possible to align the `background` of a `View` in android. I have an image as a `BitmapDrawable` that I would like to fill and align it's right edge with the `View`.

I was using the `Gravity.CENTER` value in order to keep the `background`'s contents centered, but now I need to have the image as the `background`, but align its right edge to the `View`'s right edge, while still filling the entirety of the `View`, cropping the extra.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Oops. The "What have I tried?" part is missing.

I've tried setting the gravity to `Gravity.RIGHT`, but that just ended up centering and shrinking the background.

Setting `(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT)` also had the same results.

I've tried looking on google, but it only spoke of using an `ImageView`, but I need to have `View`s in this `View`.

So, thats what I've tried and I don't know what else to do.

***EDIT 2:***

To be clear, I'm talking about ***[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)***

Comment: Are you talking specifically of an `ImageView`? Or any `View` object? I had done something similar for ImageViews that I may be able to help with but doubt it would work on other View objects.

Comment: @TheCapn I know how to do it with an `ImageView`, but I'm talking about the `background` property of a `View`. Thanks, though!

Comment: Well my solution wouldn't work then. I had used a `LayerDrawable` to remove the need for a background and provided me a means to control the `BitmapDrawable`'s bounds. Perhaps this link will help you however: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2782035/804773

Comment: @TheCapn That's odd. Thats what I'm doing, but in Java code. Its not an image in my bundle, but rather a dynamic image, so I can't use XML quite the same way. However, thats a great find. I wonder why it doesn't work for me..