# how to add a centerred background to activity_mail.xml

Tags: android, user-interface

This is how my activity_mail.xml starts can I add a simple line here to add a background image or is there more to it?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
```

This is for a tablet app and I want the image center aligned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781593/background-image-placement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

and optionally,

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

if you want to maintain image ratio and within the layout.