# Set android background to a specific location

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I used the following code to set background for an activity:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

It works but I have a small problem, the image isn't supposed to be strecthed through the whole screen, I want the image to be somewhere specific on the screen. How do I do it?

Comment: Look into layouts and the Image view

Comment: specific means where do you want to keep. ? Center in page or left or right ?

Comment: Maybe this is what your are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2782035/1176435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the image any where of your page  you should use root layout as Relative layout. Because it might have lot of user friendly attributes like **align center inparent, bottom of page align left and below and above properties** So please try with that.